# Best things to do while in Pittsburgh - Food, historical sites, generally time well spent?

Tags: sightseeing, restaurants, ecotourism, pittsburgh

I will be in Pittsburgh for a meeting and will have a few days to explore the city. I love trying new dining experiences, historical and out-doorsy stuff, and generally anything that makes the city special. Does anyone have recommendations for me?

To make this question more objective: What are the highest rated restaurants/historical places/attractions according to travel experts?

Comment: Eat an authentic Philly Cheese steak http://www.visitphilly.com/articles/philadelphia/top-10-spots-for-authentic-philly-cheesesteaks/

Comment: @Simon Right state wrong side of it.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Unfortunately as your question stands it would be considered non-constructive as per [FAQ](http://travel.stackexchange.com/faq) as a list question with answer being subjective.

Comment: @Karlson What they only do them in Philidelphia ? I guess your right though, its not a characteristic of Pittsburgh, i'm sure they still sell them though....yum

Comment: @Simon, you won't find many cheesesteaks in Pittsburgh, and certainly not particularly "authentic" ones.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier Fair Enough. But then again if you take that view point: Do you get an authentic curry in London ?

Comment: Is there enough to do in Pittsburgh one can make a list? :D

Comment: @Vince Depends on what you're looking for...

Comment: @Simon London, as a major metropolis, is not a fair comparison to Pittsburgh. But suppose instead you were in Gloucester or Bristol for a meeting. Would it make any sense to advise someone to get "authentic" stottie cake with pease pudding? Pittsburgh arguably has more in common with Cleveland, and Philadelphia with Baltimore, than they do with each other.

Comment: So... no good philly cheesesteak (or cheesecakes?) but surely there must be a few gems to this city!

Comment: @choster Agreed, points taken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primanti brothers is an excellent and iconic sandwich place in Pittsburgh. [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primanti_Brothers) has a list of notable mentions this enterprise has received. There are multiple locations in the city.

[The Cathedral of Learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathedral_of_Learning) is the second tallest university building in the world and houses 29 [nationality rooms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationality_Rooms) which are a must visit.

The [Duquesne incline](http://www.popularpittsburgh.com/pittsburgh-info/pittsburgh-aroundtown/duquesne-incline.aspx) is an incline plan railroad first started in 1887, scaling Mt.Washington and having a brilliant view of the Pittsburgh downtown and the confluence of the Allegheny, Ohio and the Monogahela rivers.

If you are the type, there are a bunch of museums including The Carnegie Museum of Natural History, the Hienz History Center detailing the sports legacies of the Steelers and The Andy Warhol Museum (Andy Warhol was a native of Pittsburgh and a leading figure in the pop art movement).

Also, if you are interested in bridges, Pittsburgh has the world record for most bridges, I beleive 446 of them, beating Venice which was historically considered the City of Bridges.

P.S. This does not strictly come under the city of Pittsburgh, but an hour's drive from the city is Frank Lloyd Wright's famous [Fallingwater](http://www.popularpittsburgh.com/pittsburgh-info/pittsburgh-aroundtown/duquesne-incline.aspx).

Comment: Hey, awesome answer! I'll visit every one of them.   Does anyone else have a highly acclaimed restaurant/attraction to share? Is Fallingwater worth the trip?

Comment: Personal opinion here, but I thought Fallingwater was lovely, especially so in the Fall.

Comment: Also Andrew Ferrier, I am personally not a big fan either of Primanti's, but jake9115 did ask for what Pittsburgh was known for :)